# How do I design table for an object that changes role in Database

Tags: database, oop, database-design

I am rewriting an application that allows people to transfer money from one person to another. So basically there is the Sender and Recipient. Originally in the table, I created a One-Many relationship between the Sender and Recipient.

Now, there is a new requirement where the same Sender can also be the Recipient in a Transaction and also a Recipient can become a Sender (ie the Recipient can send the money back to the Sender). This then seems to me that there is now no point in having separate Sender and Recipient tables.

Another layer of difficulty is that, if I go down this route of single table, how do I cater for the requirement that a Sender must register a Recipient. That is for a Sender, I must be able to show who his/her Recipients are even if that Sender has not sent money to them yet but has only registered them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started.

- **Person** exists.
- **Sender** is a **person**.
- **Recipient** is a **person**.
- **Sender** registered a **Recipient**
- **Sender** transfered `Amount` to **Recipient** at `TransactionTime`.

---

[image]

Comment: How does this handle multiple accoutns for the same person?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens it does not. It is not an ERD for the app the OP is writing; he is simply stuck with sender-recipient role.

Answer (score 1):

Your premise of a single table is absurd; for a start, you will need these entities at a minimum:

- AccountOwner
- Account
- RegisteredSender
- RegisteredRecipient
- Transaction

Play with this setup a bit, and callback with any specific difficulties you encounter.

Comment: With the entities above, what happens when a RegisteredSender transfers money to him/herself. In that case, the RegisteredSender is also the RegisteredRecipient. Does the RegisteredSender register him/herself as a RegisteredRecipients? Then you have another case where, a RegisteredRecipient initiates a transfer so, they are then the Sender and a RegisteredSender will now be the Recipient. This requirement may seem far fetched but its real.

Comment: That's why Account is one of the minimally required entities; so that a person can transfer funds from one account they own to another account they own. Think about how the entities I listed relate to each other, and then look for any holes that may exist.

Answer (score 1):

A sender is not a sender. A sender is a Person (or more generically a Legal Party), that may *play the role* of a sender, or recipient, or both.

```
create table Party (
  id serial primary key,
  name text not null
);

create table Payment (
  from_party_id int not null references party(id),
  to_party_id int not null references party(id),
  paid_at timestamp not null default current_timestamp,
  check (from_party_id <> to_party_id)
);

create table Registered_Recipients (
  sender_id int not null references party(id),
  recipient_id int not null references party(id),
  check (sender_id <> recipient_id)
);
```